# Kong is not able to find the custom plugin

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I am trying to load a custom plugin in Kong. I installed the plugin using `luarocks make` which gave me an output `kong-circuit-breaker 1.0.4-1 is now installed in /usr/local (license: MIT)` . Now if I try to restart my kong docker container and then restart kong, Kong runs successfully but this plugin is not loaded. After being stuck here for pretty long time I started setting the env variable of my Kong container, `KONG_PLUGINS=bundled,kong-circuit-breaker` and now the kong container fails to run everytime with a msg `plugin is enabled but not installed`. I even tried setting `LUA_PACKAGE_PATH` environment variable of my kong container to point to my plugin directories but of no use. Any idea why this is happenning and how can I successfully load custom plugins in my Kong?

Comment: Have you try to set into kng configuration `lua_package_path = /<path-to-plugin-location>/?.lua;;` ?

Answer (score 1):

you should not put `kong-` in the plugin name.

this should be:

```
KONG_PLUGINS=bundled,circuit-breaker
```

Kong will look for kong.plugins.YOURPLUGIN
thats why you should not put `kong-`

Comment: Thanks @Orel for the hint... atleast I have changed my error. When I am saying kong start in pongo shell.... I am seeing below error.... can you please assist here.   

Error: 
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/start.lua:75: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/start.lua:64: nginx: [error] init_by_lua error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:515: error loading plugin schemas: on plugin 'check-x-header': check-x-header plugin is enabled but not installed;
no plugin found

Comment: stack traceback:
 [C]: in function 'assert'
 /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:515: in function 'init'
 init_by_lua:3: in main chunk

stack traceback:
 [C]: in function 'error'
 /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/start.lua:75: in function 'cmd_exec'
 /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:88: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:88>
 [C]: in function 'xpcall'
 /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:88: in function

Comment: </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:45>
 /kong/bin/kong:9: in function 'file_gen'
 init_worker_by_lua:47: in function <init_worker_by_lua:45>
 [C]: in function 'xpcall'
 init_worker_by_lua:54: in function <init_worker_by_lua:52>

Comment: Perhaps open another question.
The message is quite clear you didn't install the `check-x-header` plugin

Comment: Here it is... Thanks.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69085647/how-to-install-custom-plugin-in-locally-setup-kong